# Android's menu button in Unity3d apps

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-softkeyboard

[image: A menu button appeared on my app]

As seen above, a menu button appears when I run my app. I want to hide the button as usual. I didn't know this problem till I changed my phone to Nexus5 using soft keys.  I developed this app in Unity3d, and there was no code receiving messages from soft keys except a back button. Of course, nothing happens when I push the menu button. How can I control configuration about this in an Unity project?

Comment: That menu doesn't normally appear in Unity Android apps as far as I know (not seeing it on my device). Have you added any plugins to your build that might be adding this?  What comes up when you tap that menu?

Comment: I didn't install any plugins and nothing happens when I tap the menu as I wrote the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Unity -> File -> Build Setting… -> Switch Platform to Android. Then, select Player Settings -> Bundle Identifier -> Copy Bundle Identifier.
2. Go to Assets/Plugins/Android

Create new file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Or you can go to /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines
And copy file AndroidManifest.xml, and then adding

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Note: targetSdkVersion >=14 is Ok, (i.e: 15, 16…)

Rebuild your app

Good luck!

Comment: Good, they was unintentionally set to 6, both of the android:minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. Then I removed the uses-sdk tag instead of increasing version numbers, and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unity handles those with [KeyCode.Escape and KeyCode.Menu](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/61851-How-to-Use-hardware%28H-W%29-MENU-KEY).

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
        //user pressed back key
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Menu)) {
        //user pressed menu key
    }
}
```

If you want to hide the softkeys, you might try [this suggestion from the forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/172024-How-to-hide-Android-Softkeys-Navigation-Bars).